# Exporting a bundle with dependencies with another bundles

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I have this OSGI configuration:

```
/configurations
   config.ini
   somebundle.properties
/plugins
   bundleA
   bundleB
osgi-3.4.2-R34x_v2008826-1230.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.4.0.v20080421-2006.jar
org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.2.201.R34x_v20080819.jar
com.test.arquitectura.osgi.ConfiguratorModule_1.0.0.jar
```

My config.ini is like this:

```
osgi.bundles=org.eclipse.equinox.common@2:start, \
    org.eclipse.update.configurator@3:start, \
    com.test.arquitectura.osgi.ConfiguratorModule_1.0.0.jar@3:start
osgi.clean = true
eclipse.ignoreApp=true
osgi.parentClassLoader=app
```

So, AFAIK, when I execute

```
java -Xms256M -Xmx1280M -jar osgi-3.4.2-R34x_v20080826-1230.jar
```

It reads config.ini so with equinox.common and update.configurator bundles it "detects" all bundles deployed in /plugins folder. After that, the ConfiguratorModule (a custom bundle) just reads all bundles in the context and executes start method of each one (bundleA and bundleB). I have an eclipse project (bundleC), which uses some clases defined in bundleA and bundleB, so the MANIFEST.MF is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: BundleC Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.test.bundlec
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: com.test.bundlec.Activator
Import-Package: javax.naming,javax.sql,org.osgi.framework;version="1.3
 .0",org.osgi.util.tracker;version="1.3.1"
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Require-Bundle: com.test.BundleA;bundle-version="1.0.0",
com.test.BundleB;bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

So, I want to generate a plugin (jar) file for the bundleC project. As there are two bundles in the "Require-bundle" option, those projects (BundleA and BundleB) should be in the bundleC classpath, isn´t it? So, in that case, I just generate the bundle (by exporting it as "Plugin Development") and place the new bundle in the plugin folder. Is there something I'm missing?

Well, in case all I´ve said is correct, here is my problem. I have the plugin jar file for BundleA and BundleB but I don´t have the source code of them, so I get an error when exporting BundleC to a jar plugin because, as it seem obvious, it can´t find the required classes it uses from BundleA and BundleB. Is there any way to generate the plugin without those required-bundles in the classpath?

I´ve tried to "decompile" them and then create the projects, and adding them in the classpath of BundleC. I can generate the plugin, then I place it in the plugins folder, but when execute the osgi enviroment, the bundleC is not found. What I´m doing wrong?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please post the exact error you get, any stack traces etc

Answer (score 0):

In order to use something from BundleA and BundleB, they need to export it ( for example they can export a class for usage by other bundles). Then in BundleC you need to wait until BundleA and BundleB are loaded (for example with implementation of BundleListener, though this scenario is usually made with services and ServiceTracker).